# SQL hierarchyid depth first vs breadth first: using one over the other?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchy

I know about `Breadth First Search` and `Depth First Search`. I read [this page](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/62204/), and also on SO, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657174/what-is-breadth-first-search-useful-for) too.

What I wanna know is some practical scenerio where I would use depth first over breadth search. Though I third question link I provided is kinda similar, my question is more geared toward `t-sql` and `SQL Server 2008/2012` performance.

Also, if I use one over other can anyone show me an example how much (worst case scenario) performance impact can I have? Say, if I adopt a `dfs`, and I have 50 children in first node, and I am searching for 2nd node, the `dfs` would be about 50 times slow from what I can think, because it would first have to transverse 50 children then it will come to second node. Is this so or not? I mean is it just like this direct relation btw the performance or otherwise?

Lastly, to repeat my question again, although it may (most likely will be) application and requirement specific, I would like to know some practical scenario where I would use one over the other, and what might be the performance cost of choosing one over the other? Also, I am am maintain a category catalog what should I choose? Say, I am maintaining a books category catalog something like : `science => physics => astronomy` and so on, which one would be the best? `dfs` or `bfs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.  Depending on the data, use the search method most likely to visit the desired node first.